# Would this isolated AC peak voltage detection circuit work?

Tags: opto-isolator, isolation, efficiency, voltage-detector

[image]

I have adapted the circuit from Michael's circuit in [Efficient method for isolated detection of AC voltage without a stepdown transformer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246679/efficient-method-for-isolated-detection-of-ac-voltage-without-a-stepdown-transfo) to detect on either side of the positive half-cycle peaks, rather than at zero crossing.  I did this for two reasons, one being that I would like to simplyfy the circuit, and secondly, to save some energy - and only drive the opto-coupler on either side of the positive peak.

Does anyone see any disadvantages/dangers with this design, besides having a much shorter time period in which to read the output pulse?

If I recorded the midpoint in time between the falling and rising edge of the output on one half cycle, I am hoping to detect within 1mS of the voltage peak.

Comment: it will detect peak. Do you have any specs for accuracy?

Comment: Also keep in mind that the [SFH6286](https://datasheet.octopart.com/SFH6286-4-Vishay-datasheet-5318503.pdf) (and all optos) introduce delays.  This one could be up to 6µs - perhaps not important, or critical for your application.  Faster ones are available if needed, like the [HCPL](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/hcpl2631-d.pdf) series (100ns max.)

Comment: Thanks Tony, I have added my desired accuracy to the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit itself will not detect a peak, it will simple create a voltage range that has some transfer function that converts a half-wave rectified 240vac mains signal to a low-voltage (between 0-3.3v) that another circuit (or device) operating at this voltage range can be used to detect the peak.

Typically. A real peak detector will be a diode or other switching mechanism followed by a capacitor to trap the signal at its peak voltage and then discharged to allow another signal to captured and measured.

I would label you circuit a rectifier and level shifter.

Comment: Thanks GT, I have updated the title of this question to something which I hope is more appropriate